# Spring Batch File Writer Exception handling

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch process which has following kind of code.

```
<step id="step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <chunk reader="reader1" writer="writer1" commit-interval="10"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>

<bean id="writer1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" ref="resourceFlatFile" />   
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <property name="transactional" value="true" />
    <property name = "lineAggregator"> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator" >
            <property name="delimiter" value=""/>
            <property name ="fieldExtractor"> 
                <bean class="com.path.MyExtractor" />
            </property>  
        </bean>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Basically my reader gives set of records from database. My writer (writer1) writes it to a flat file. If there is any problem in writing a record to the file, I would like to mark that record status as failed in database. So how to handle these kind of scenarios? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
My question is if I get any kind of exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you look into using a [ItemWriteListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html) and update the status of the failed records in the onWriteError implementation.

Comment: I assume that the ItemWriter will continue to the next record after the exception?

Comment: It depends on how you have your job defined, but in general and by default, yes.

Comment: I don't see how this will work. You don't get a reference to the read item from the itemWriteListener.